# Invalid pointer не могу найти ошибку

Tags: c++

Ошибка в куче. Пробовала все, ничего не получается.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <typeinfo>

class Parent {
public:
    Parent() {
        x = new int(0);
    }

     ~Parent() { 
        delete x; 
    };

     void init(Parent obj, std::vector<Parent*>& vec, int repeat)
     {
         for (int i = 0; i < repeat; i++)
         {
             *obj.x += 1;
             vec.push_back(&obj);
         }
     }
public:
    int* x;
};

class Child : public Parent {
public:
    Child() {
        *x = 100;
    };

    ~Child()
    {
        delete x;
    }
};


int main()
{
    int repeat;
    std::cout << "Enter the number of repetitions : ";
    std::cin >> repeat;

    std::vector<Parent*> vecX;
    Parent objPrnt;
    Child objChld;

    objPrnt.init(objPrnt, vecX, repeat);
    objChld.init(objChld, vecX, repeat);

    for (int i = 0; i < vecX.size(); i++)
    {
        delete vecX.at(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Как минимум двойное удаление - в деструкторе предка и в деструкторе потомка...

Comment: через virtual не работало, я попробовала так

Comment: @AlexanderChernin Вы что такое советуете?... Деструктор базового класса вызовется автоматически!

Comment: А `virtual` у вас нигде не работает, потому что вы не работаете со ссылками - `void init(Parent obj,` - тут передача по значению, при передаче объекта потомка происходит срезка...

Comment: @Harry да, херню спорол. Это коронавирус виноват )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как минимум двойное удаление - в деструкторе предка и в деструкторе потомка...

Но куда хуже -

```
vec.push_back(&obj);
```

Этот адрес - адрес копии переданного в функцию аргумента, который при выходе из функции исчезает, т.е. какой-то совершенно левый адрес!

А потом вы еще собираетесь его удалять. Даже если бы это был корректный адрес - он не выделен с помощью `new`, удалять его нельзя.

Я даже не могу посоветовать, как исправлять столь бредовую ситуацию...

Comment: Спасибо, основная проблема была в том, что ' Parent::init ' не видел класс  ' Child ', надо было иницализировать этот класс в самом начале.

Comment: Ой, что-то вы не то пишете... И что, все проблемы исчезли? При удалении указателя, указывающего непонятно куда? *Не верю (с) Станиславский*